# How to add all the packages of conda in PyCharm by setting conda environment?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am trying to set the conda environment in PyCharm. It sets successfully, but when displaying all the packages, it shows only a few of all the packages I have installed through conda. Here are the screenshots of my terminal showing all the conda packages

[image]

and what PyCharm shows

[image]

**Why aren't all the packages in conda also found in PyCharm?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably installed all these packages in an environment different from the one set up in PyCharm.

In the terminal you can type `conda env list` to see the list of all the environments you have. The one with the star `*` is the active one in the terminal (meaning the one you install the packages into).

You can switch to another environment by doing `source activate <environment_name>`. Then you can install the packages in the new active environment.

Another way of always installing packages in the environment your project uses in to use the embedded terminal in PyCharm.