# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dpkt'?

Tags: python-3.x, import, window, dpkt

When I run

```
import dpkt
```

It gives

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dpkt'

But I already installed dpkt.
[install dpkt cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20egm.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I am using window10, python3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I found out that when I installing the dpkt module, it was getting installed onto an environment different than the one I was using in pyCharm.

I found the answer to this post very helpful to explain my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608375/2411380

I fixed my issue by using the terminal inside pyCharm to install dpkt, then it worked.

I also found a suggestion to use all packages installed in conda inside pyCharm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097897/2411380